# Fabric instance crashing when creating custom item group

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I tried making a custom item group for my mod but when I run the code, the game instantly crashes.

fabric 1.19.2

```
package com.end3r.cripplingteas.item;

import com.end3r.cripplingteas.CripplingTeasMod;
import com.end3r.cripplingteas.Registry.ModItems;
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.client.itemgroup.FabricItemGroupBuilder;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.util.Identifier;

public class ModItemGroup {
    public static final ItemGroup CRIPPLINGTEAS = FabricItemGroupBuilder.build(
            new Identifier(CripplingTeasMod.teas, "Crippling Teas"), () -> new ItemStack(ModItems.BASIC_TEA))
            ;

}
```

i tried writing a custom item group for my mod using FabricItemGroupBuilder

logs:

```
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not execute entrypoint stage 'main' due to errors, provided by 'teas'!
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.lambda$invoke0$0(EntrypointUtils.java:51)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.util.ExceptionUtil.gatherExceptions(ExceptionUtil.java:33)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke0(EntrypointUtils.java:49)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke(EntrypointUtils.java:35)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.Hooks.startClient(Hooks.java:52)
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.<init>(MinecraftClient.java:523)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:184)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:56)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:461)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23)
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.end3r.cripplingteas.Registry.ModItems.<clinit>(ModItems.java:21)
    at com.end3r.cripplingteas.CripplingTeasMod.onInitialize(CripplingTeasMod.java:12)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke0(EntrypointUtils.java:47)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: net.minecraft.util.InvalidIdentifierException: Non [a-z0-9/._-] character in path of location: teas:Crippling Teas
    at net.minecraft.util.Identifier.<init>(Identifier.java:140)
    at net.minecraft.util.Identifier.<init>(Identifier.java:144)
    at com.end3r.cripplingteas.item.ModItemGroup.<clinit>(ModItemGroup.java:11)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the identifier rules. `Crippling Teas` isn't valid as:

- contains a space
- with upper cases

Actually, identifier should only be like `crippling_teas`.